# how can i completely close my C# program?

Tags: c#

I already learned python and am trying to learn C# by recreating one of my python text based games. in the game there is a main method which is where you can look to fight something, see stats, coins, shop, turn on or off music and quit the program. in python its simply quit() but i cant figure how to just stop the program in C#. i asked people on discord but they cant understand the question and go on rants about random things so ill show the python code then my C# code so far if that helps you understand.
Python:

```
def Main():
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    choice = input("\n1.fight \n2.Shop \n3.Stats \n4.See coins \n5.music on \n6.music off \n7.quit \nInput:")
    if choice == "1":
        battlestate()

    elif choice == "2":
        Shop()

    elif choice == "3":
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print("health: ",character.health)
        print("strength: ",character.strength)
        print("armor: ",character.armor)

    elif choice == "4":
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print("you have: ",character.coins," coins")
        Main()

    elif choice == "4":
        battlestate()

    elif choice == "5":
        music = True
        music = winsound.PlaySound("311 - Love from Afar.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_ALIAS )
        Main()

    elif choice == "6":
        music = False
        music = winsound.PlaySound("311 - Love from Afar.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_ALIAS )
        Main()
        
    elif choice == "7":
        quit()

    else:
        print("i dont understand, please try again!")
        Main()
```

C#

```
class Program
    {
        private void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("1.Fight \n7.Quit");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (choice == "1")
            {
                BattleState();
            }
            else if(choice == "7")
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're wanting to exit the entire program? Have you tried `Environment.Exit(0)`?

Comment: [HCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire_(computing))

Comment: Have you observed what happens when `choice` is anything other than `"1"`?

Comment: @Jaskier thank you this works, do you know how i can archive the question so people can keep answering but people can see answer?

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews the C# for the python one yes, thats why i have the else statement then it says it doesnt understand then calls the main function again. im going to do this for the C# one to

Comment: You'll probably get away with it because of tail-call optimization, but recursively calling `Main` instead of just using a loop is not good practice in either language. That's why we have looping constructs like `while`.

Comment: @Lore I was asking about your C# code.

Comment: @Lore, you can mark the posted answer as such and it will close out your question. People can still interact with the question (comment and supply more answers). User15119845 has a great solution for this posted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command to close an application of console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682408/) and [What is the command to exit a Console application in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286056/) and [To exit the console window in C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374998/) and [Why is the console window closing immediately once displayed my output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/) and [How to implement a console menu having submenus in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760184/)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything, the program will terminate and shutdown on it's own. The real question should be how do you stop the program from shutting down.

```
private void Main()
    { 

        bool running = true;

        Console.Write("1.Fight \n7.Quit");
        while(running) {
           string choice = Console.ReadLine();
           if (choice == "1")
           {
               BattleState();
            } 
           else if(choice == "7")
           {
               running = false;
           }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Shutting Down...");
    }
```